# Solved. Lubuntu 14.04.4 ssh-agent configuration: what I am missing

Tags: ssh-agent

There are many questions around regarding ssh-agent, but none of the situations described seems to correspond to my problem.

First, I am using Lubuntu 14.04.4.

I have followed the instructions (found in arch wiki):

```
$ ssh-agent
$ eval $(ssh-agent)
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_dsa
```

But when I do:

```
$ ssh -p 22 jofre@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

it asks for the password.

(There is an actual ip address, I just do not feel like sharing it ;-) )

I found somewhere to verify the following:

```
$ echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK
/tmp/ssh-tw1EdcXYFnDd/agent.6550
```

which I understand as a valid output.

So what am I missing?

I also tried using ssh-pass but nothing happens.

Otherwise, I have no problem login in manually, it is just a pain in the ass to type constantly the password...

Thanks in advance.

Muru ask about the output of

```
    OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
    debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
    debug1: Connecting to xxx.xxx [xx.xxx] port xxx.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /home/jofre/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
    debug1: identity file /home/jofre/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/jofre/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/jofre/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/jofre/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/jofre/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/jofre/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
    debug1: identity file /home/jofre/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.7 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
    debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
    debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
    debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
    debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug1: Server host key: ccccccccccccccccccccccccc (modified by Jofre)
    debug1: Host '[xxxxxxxxx]:yyy' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /home/jofre/.ssh/known_hosts:6
    debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
    debug2: kex_derive_keys
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug2: key: /home/jofre/.ssh/id_rsa (xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx),
    debug2: key: /home/jofre/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
    debug2: key: /home/jofre/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
    debug2: key: /home/jofre/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/jofre/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
    debug1: Trying private key: /home/jofre/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
    debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
    debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
    Enter passphrase for key '/home/jofre/.ssh/id_dsa':
```

I have replaced what I considered sensitive information by xxxxxxx or cccccccc.

Anyway thanks for asking for more info.

Update 27/05/2016:
Following the observation of Waltinator that I was getting a message regarding the format of the file, I checked it, and not found any obvious mistaken. Normal, as that file has never edited by hand.

I simply give up, and generate a new password-less key and use ssh-copy-id as suggested by Julen. It works. I have marked the title as solved.

Comment: Please [Edit] your post to include the output of `ssh -vv -p 22 jofre@xxx.xxx`

Comment: If what you want is just to log in without password, you could also use `ssh-copy-id jofre@xxx.xxx`

Answer (score 0):

See which keys are in your keyring with `ssh-add -l`.

The last several log lines:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/jofre/.ssh/id_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/jofre/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: key_parse_private_pem: PEM_read_PrivateKey failed
debug1: read PEM private key done: type <unknown>
Enter passphrase for key '/home/jofre/.ssh/id_dsa':
```

Show that your `ssh` command sends your public key from `/home/jofre.ssh.id_rsa`, and waits for a reply. The `sshd` server on the other end does not accept your private key (as @julen-larrucea: said, use `ssh-copy-id` to get a useable key to the other end).

Then, your `ssh` tries to use a different key file, `/home/jofre/.ssh/id_dsa`, but the file doesn't have the right format (`missing begin marker`) so it gives up and prompts you for a passphrase for `/home/jofre/.ssh/id_dsa`, the malformed file. Read `man ssh-keygen`, and probably `mv /home/jofre/.ssh/id_dsa\{,.hidden\}` to rename it to `/home/jofre/.ssh/id_dsa.hidden` which will make `ssh` ignore it, and keep it where you can get it back if.